# Facebook scope PHP

Tags: php, facebook, email, scope

I'm trying to work with Facebook's default PHP website integration and authentication.
When a user logs in, I'm able to request permissions to get various information from the user.

---

> **This question is kind of old. Please take note of harkirat1892's comment.**
>
> "If someone using Facebook SDK v4.4 is stumbling across this question, the answer by Dhiraj won't >work in that case as there is a small change. You don't have to include redirect_uri in the array >passed to getLoginUrl.
>
> As per v4.4, getLoginUrl should work like:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
    'scope'         => 'email,user_checkins, user_birthday'
)
);
```

> The various scopes can be found here: [Facebook permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#referencehttps://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference)."

---

It was really easy to figure out how to do it with the JavaScript one, but I'm confused where to specify the scope in the PHP example.

Basically, I just want to request for permission to access their email & location and maybe some other information.

Here is the code I'm working with:
(It's modified slightly, but it is almost an exact match to what they had.)

```
<?php
    define('YOUR_APP_ID', '---------');
    define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '------------');

    //Uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
    require 'facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
      'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
    ));

    $FBUID = $facebook->getUser();
?>

<?php  if ($FBUID) {
    $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $FBUID); ?>

<?php $FBName = $userInfo['name'];?>
    <!--
      Welcome <? // = $userInfo['name'] ?> -->

<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
<?php } ?>

    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '---------------',
                status     : true,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true,
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        };

        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
    </script>
```

Comment: Wow sorry, I finally found it on the links on the side.
Replace: <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
With: <fb:login-button scope="email"></fb:login-button>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Apps: Additional permissions](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above is great but, Facebook just loves to change things up.  The best answer checked off on this forum is for a version of Facebook SDK, which is out of date.  Similar to the example above, here is how you would request permissions or a scope for version 5.0.

```
session_start();

$F = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'      => 'app-id',
  'app_secret'  => 'app-secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
 ]);

$helper      = $F->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$callBackUrl = "http://website.com/callBack.php";
$scope       = array("email","user_likes");
$loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($url,$scope);
```

Also, I noticed the answer above is a request for "user_checkins" which I believe is deprecated.  The most current reference list of permissions is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#referencehttps://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference).

Answer (score 2):

This is how you typically specify scope in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) (check **[the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)**):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
    'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
));

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'scope'         => 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,manage_pages,email,user_checkins',
        'redirect_uri'  => $redirectURI
    )
);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If someone using Facebook SDK v4.4 is stumbling across this question, the answer by Dhiraj won't work in that case as there is a small change. You don't have to include redirect_uri in the array passed to getLoginUrl.

As per v4.4, getLoginUrl should work like:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
    'scope'         => 'email, user_checkins, user_birthday'
)
```

);

The various scopes can be found here: [Facebook permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference).

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? Please give a brief reason?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same issue and got below solution. Might it help you :

Open your app in facebook developer console and then select app reviews section on left side.

Submit Items for Approval. Some permissions need to take approval from facebook before using.

:)